# Changing the ContentStringFormat property of a Label in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, label, code-behind

Is it possible to change the ContentStringFormat property of a Label in code?

Take this XAML:

```
<Label ContentFormatString="Hello {0}" Content="John" x:Name="MyLabel" />
```

And this C#:

```
MyLabel.ContentFormatString = "Bye {0}";
```

When you debug this, you will see the property's value actually changes, but this is not visualized in the UI.

Is this possible?

Comment: What possible?  You said it is working.

Comment: Heh, indeed. I forgot a "not". Added that now. So the problem is that it is not visualized in the UI.

Comment: Interesting, just tried this and not working on a label. Can you use a TextBlock instead? That way you can create the new binding with stringformat in codebehind. Would like to know why it is not working with a Label though.

Comment: [Worth a check here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/866f7934-8b10-4872-b306-122674fad5fa/label-contentstringformat-and-binding-stringformat?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not very elegant, but this works:

```
var content = MyLabel.Content;
MyLabel.Content = null;
MyLabel.ContentStringFormat = "Bye {0}";
MyLabel.Content = content;
```